# Setting a controller property on application controller after application ready

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set my main application view headline to the current company name. Which I need to fetch via ajax "/company.json".

In my ApplicationController I have a "companyName" property and a method called "loadCompanyName" that will fetch the companyName. The question is, How do I reference this instanced controller from the Application ready function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the new one you should prefer to do it in the the App.ready() function.

Usuallly I would do it in the setupController() function of the ApplicationRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.loadCompanyName();
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the old router API (=ember-pre), you can use:

```
var controller = App.get("router.applicationController");
controller.loadCompanyName();
```